# Single source file for both Python and C

Tags: python, c, macros

I'm writing a small module, which will be used in both Python and C. I can write a Python version and a C version, or I can compile the C version and then integrate in Python. But since the module is mostly math calculations, which are basically the same in Python and C, I'm considering writing a single file that can both import in Python and compile as C source.

Here is a basic trick:

```
#if 1 /*
    write Python code here
''' */
    write C code here
#endif // '''
```

So the Python interpreter will ignore the C part while the C compiler will ignore the Python part.

For example, the following `foo.py`:

```
#if 1 /*
from math import sin, cos, sqrt
''' */
#include <math.h>
#endif // '''

#if 1 /*
def rotation(axis, angle):
    matrix = [0.] * 9
    ''' */
void rotation(double *axis, double angle, double *matrix) {
    double sa, ca, ia, r, x, y, z, xx, yy, zz;
    double cayz, caxz, caxy, iayz, iaxy, iaxz, sax, say, saz;
#endif // '''
    sa = sin(angle);
    ca = cos(angle);
    ia = 1. - ca;
    r = sqrt(axis[0] * axis[0] + axis[1] * axis[1] + axis[2] * axis[2]);
    x = axis[0] / r;
    y = axis[1] / r;
    z = axis[2] / r;
    xx = x * x;
    yy = y * y;
    zz = z * z;
    cayz = ca * (yy + zz);
    caxz = ca * (xx + zz);
    caxy = ca * (xx + yy);
    iayz = ia * y * z;
    iaxz = ia * x * z;
    iaxy = ia * x * y;
    sax = sa * x;
    say = sa * y;
    saz = sa * z;
    matrix[0] = cayz + xx;
    matrix[1] = iaxy - saz;
    matrix[2] = iaxz + say;
    matrix[3] = iaxy + saz;
    matrix[4] = caxz + yy;
    matrix[5] = iayz - sax;
    matrix[6] = iaxz - say;
    matrix[7] = iayz + sax;
    matrix[8] = caxy + zz;
#if 1 /*
    return matrix
''' */
    }
#endif // '''
```

In Python:

```
from foo import rotation

print(rotation([1., 2., 3.], 4.))
```

In C:

```
#include "foo.py"

int main() {
    double axis[3] = {1., 2., 3.};
    double angle = 4.;
    double matrix[9];
    rotation(axis, angle, matrix);
    printf("[%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf]",
           matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2],
           matrix[3], matrix[4], matrix[5],
           matrix[6], matrix[7], matrix[8]);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm wondering if I can go a little bit further, to use some better patterns such as macros, to define:

- global (const) arrays and matrices
- simple control flow, conditions and loops

or some other improvements.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against mixing code in the same source file... Just looking at `#include "foo.py"` is going to make people go "what the....!".... If anything, you should probably have a look at [Cython](https://cython.org/) - write it in Python syntax and generate the C include file from that and use that file... will make life simpler than mixing things in the same file

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I think what you're doing is abominable.  Clever, but abominable.  The extra work you're expending to make this Rube Goldberg device work would be better devoted to writing the bits needed to wrap the C code in a Python extension module.  Not only will that be more maintainable and less likely to trip you up in unexpected ways, but Python will probably see better performance.

Comment: I wasn't expecting that many people like this way. I know there are a few "simple" methods to integrate C in Python. But all of them needs compilation. And this is one way to do that with neither compilation nor duplication.

Comment: I'd rather spend time writing nice looking python and then writing an AST translation that can convert the Python to C

Comment: "_since the module is mostly math calculations, which are basically the same in Python and C_"  I don't seen that that is any kind of valid justification - it is still separate code.  What is the benefit of placing in a single file rather then say two files in a single directory?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem with this proposal is that Python is interpreted whilst C is compiled.

While you pass the C source through the pre-processor once, and it is default behaviour for a C build toolchain, for Python you would have to build a tool that would pass the .py file through the C pre-processor, and hen pass the output to the Python interpreter every time you wanted to run the code.

Your runtime would require both the Python interpreter and your special tool, and the code would no longer be portable to system without that dependency.

It is a complicated solution to a problem that does not exist.

Comment: No, I don't have to "build a tool that would pass the .py file through the C pre-processor". `foo.py` is both pure Python and ANSI C. No extra tools needed (compiler, Cython, etc). It is a solution with no duplication, no compilation, and no dependency.